# NVIDIA NVS GPUs: What are they for?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

Why buy a NVIDIA NVS instead of an AMD 7000 with Eyefinity? A NVS support many monitors. But a 7750 also supports many monitors. Yet the first costs 400$ while the second 130$.

NVIDIA Quadro are way better than gaming cards when used for 3D Gaming Development.

NVS are good for what?

Answer (score 3):

[NVS](http://www.nvidia.com/object/desktop-nvs.html) series cards are meant for business 2D applications. i.e. high resolution/multi display configuration but poor 3D performance. AMD's Eyefinity cards would have way better 3D performance.